# Boost asio проблема закрытия забинженного сокета

Tags: c++, boost, asio

На первый запуск, бинд успешно проходит, при перезапуске программы кричит, что адрес уже используется, освобождается адрес через пару минут.

Если не вызывать shutdown и close, то все биндится каждый раз успешно(при перезапуске программы естественно)

```
    boost::asio::io_service _ioService;
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket _socket(_ioService);

    boost::system::error_code err;
    _socket.open(boost::asio::ip::tcp::v4(), err);

 _socket.bind(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1250), err);


    if (err.value())
    {
        cout << err.value() << endl;
        cout << err.message() << endl;
    }

    _socket.connect(boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(boost::asio::ip::address_v4::from_string("127.0.0.1"), 1500), err);

    //_socket.shutdown(_socket.shutdown_both);
    //_socket.close(err);
```

Comment: Т.е. Вы запускаете второй экземпляр программы? Или первый закрываете и запускаете его повторно и тогда идет "крик"?

Comment: @MaxZS, первый закрываю и запускаю его повторно

Comment: Подключения с другой стороны закрываются к этому моменту или висят еще? Если другая сторона до этого момента не закрыла подключение, то тогда как бы поведение правильное и логичное. С Вашей стороны соединение закрыто и повторное подключение может словить блуждающие по сети посланные второй стороной фрагменты сообщения. Поэтому и биндится повторно только через пару минут. Ну а если Вы не закрываете соединение, то это как бы признак временной потери связи (ну вылетела программа) и Вы типа восстановив соединение продолжаете принимать все с другой стороны.

Comment: @MaxZS, почему при стандартном деструкторе (без вызова close), все хорошо отрабатывает? Да и при винсок я такого поведения не встречал, да и при закрытии проги винда чистит все обычно.

Comment: Я же описал, что если Вы не закрываете соединение явно, то, скажем так, сеть считает, что сокет все еще в использовании, на него можно слать данные, а программа просто могла временно вылететь и соединение вот-вот восстановится. Именно с бустом я не сталкивался, но вот в обычных сокетах (винсок) все то же самое. Возможно, просто Вы не обращали внимания, открыта или закрыта при этом другая сторона. И в обычных сокетах даже есть специальная опция для такой ситуации - `SO_REUSEADDR`. Если в бусте можно использовать опции сокетов, то вот это и будет решением Вашего вопроса.

Comment: Кстати, а что Вас побудило, если не секрет, вместо обычных сокетов `связаться` с бустом? Зачем? В чем Вы увидели преимущество?

Comment: @MaxZS, кроссплатформенно и меньше кода

Comment: Странно, а чем Вам не кроссплатформенно использование winsock? Только тем, что под win нужно подключить одну библиотеку и другой header файл? Т.е. разница будет в одном define. А вот насчет того, что меньше кода - я бы очень сильно поспорил. Но дело Ваше.